# Hibernate Insert/Set?

Tags: hibernate, set, save, sql-update, hql

Upon hibernate insert how do I set a column value as sum of pkey column and an hardcoded offest value.

```
@Column(name = "SUM_COLUMN", unique = true, nullable = false)
public void setSumColumn(Long sumColumn)
{
   this.sumColumn = pkey + 1000L;
}
```

Will this work upon `session.save(myHibernateObj);` ?

Comment: what is your pk generation strategy?

Comment: @ShayElkayam Its Identity

Comment: do you have @ Id @ GeneratedValue on your pk?

Comment: @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Comment: @ShayElkayam Its identity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not work as you expect, and that's **why**: 
`pkey` is not available to an entity before it's **persisted for the first time**.
The proper way for you to do it will be:

1) create a new Entity (`Entity myEntity = new Entity()`). 
2) set all the other fields you normally set for this entity (e.g name, etc..)
3) persist it.
 
4) Now you'll have it's id value available, so when you call `setSumColumn`, it will work as expected.

**Please note** (this is regarding the concern you've made in your comment about efficiency and "going to the database"): `persist` does not necessarily "go to" the database immediately.
so, you can still use this solution and effectively "save" the entity only once in the database. You can take a look at the following post for better understanding:

[Hibernate EntityManager persist() and database round trip count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494673/hibernate-entitymanager-persist-and-database-round-trip-count)

Comment: Thanks Shay, that would surely do it. However I would like to minimize hibernate invocations as much as possible as it would cause performance degradations under high frequency loads. Id rather have a trigger that does that job for me. Will have to explore that route.

Comment: look at my update. I think it can be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's a very important piece of information.